# Rails how to save Address from different models (Country, State, City, Address) in one single form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms, model

So what I'm trying to do is save in one single form a bunch of data. Part of that data is an **address**. **This address has been split in several models: Country, State, City and Address.**

My problem is that honestly I have no idea how to manage that in the controller. I will share what I have at the moment and hope someone can give me a clue.

**Should I do *accepts_nested_attributes_for* for all models?. How can I connect all this inherits fields or foreign key in order to process the information?**

Country Model:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states
end
```

State Model:

```
class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
end
```

City Model:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :addresses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

Address Model:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :office
end
```

Office Model:

```
class Office < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :addresses, inverse_of: :office

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

**Office Controller Strong Params for Country, State, City and Address (There are more params, I just placed those regarding to the issue I'm having):**

```
def office_params
      params.require(:office).permit(
     {
        countries_attributes: [
          :id, :name,
          states_attributes: [
            :id, :name,
            cities_attributes: [
            :id, :name,
              addresses_attributes: [
                :id, :street, :state_id
                ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },         
)
```

Office New Method:

```
def new
    @office = Office.new
    @countries = Country.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    @states = State.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    #@office.addresses.build.cities.build
    #@office.addresses.counties.states.cities.build
    #@office.addresses.build
  end
```

**Office Form:** In this form I'm using fields_for in order to nested all the fields called from their respective models. So here I need to save all information at once to several models.

```
<%= form_with(model: office, local: true, html: {class: "form-office"}) do |form| %>
        <% if office.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(office.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this office from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
            <% office.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span><%= form.label :office_name %></span>
              <%= form.text_field :office_name, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span><%= form.label :office_slug %></span>
              <%= form.text_field :office_slug, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span><%= form.label :office_email %></span>
              <%= form.text_field :office_email, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span><%= form.label :phone %></span>
              <%= form.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <h3 style="color: #B0B0B0;">Office Address</h3>
**Office Address**
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-6">
            <%= form.fields_for :countries do |country| %>
              <div class="form-group">
                <span><%= country.label :country %></span>
                <%= select_tag(:country_id, options_for_select(@countries), class: 'form-control', :prompt => "Select Country") %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= country.fields_for :states do |state| %>
                  <span><%= state.label :state %></span>
                  <%= select_tag(:state_id, options_for_select(@states), class: 'form-control', :prompt => "Select State") %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= state.fields_for :cities do |city| %>
                    <span><%= city.label :city %></span>
                    <%= city.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= city.fields_for :addresses do |address| %>
                      <span><%= address.label :street %></span>
                      <%= address.text_field :street, class: 'form-control' %>
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <span><%= address.label :zip_code %></span>
                      <%= address.text_field :zip_code, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>

      <hr>
      <h4 style="color: #B0B0B0;">Comment</h4>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 st">
            <div class="comments">
              <%= form.fields_for :comments do |comment_form| %>
                <%= render 'comment_fields', f: comment_form %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-lg' %>
          </div>
        </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Please use Transaction for saving multiple models
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for every association you want to update through `fields_for`.

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :states
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :states
end
```

However, if you do that and if you define `office_params` correctly, saving all nested models is possible with single `Office.create(office_params)` call, without worrying about setting foreign keys. 
Same goes for updating, but you will have to provide hidden `:id` form fields for nested models, so existing model instances can be found in DB.

You should also consider adding [`validates_associated`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) to models.

Comment: What do you think about the way I handle the nested attributes in the params? I mean, should I nested everything from "Parent" Country or should I nested like individually?

Same for the form. I nested everything inside Country but not so sure if I have to nested separately. Thanks